# Is this the (previous) contents of a file in this git repo?

Tags: git

I have a file I found laying around. I want to know if it came from a specific git repo, at some point in time. Exact-match comparison is good enough. How can I do this?

Comment: `Exact-match comparison` - would comparing `md5sum` be enough? If so, you can use [this script from another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32849134/3691891) like this `git-dump.sh <FILE>` and then check if any of the output file matches original file's `md5sum`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk doesn't git have sha1 hashes of all files internally already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob)

Comment: @DenysSéguret IMHO not a full duplicate, the linked question starts with a given hash. [Your asnwer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48058743/711006) clearly states that we need to generate the hash of the file and how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the SHA from a file using

```
git hash_object <file path>
```

This gives you a hash such as this one:

```
c675fb0fe881673391f078c37e594ec7a51aa222
```

It's also possible to list all (reachable) blobs and filenames using a command like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25954360) (many variations possible).

Using this, you can grep your hash:

```
git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(rest)' | grep '^[^ ]* blob' | cut -d" " -f1,3- | grep c675fb0fe881673391f078c37e594ec7a51aa222
```