# access git blobs via APIs

Tags: git, github, github-api, github-enterprise, github-api-v3

I am struggling to access my git file using git APIs.

- official Documentation : https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/
- Tha command I execute :

> curl -v -H "Authorization: token       111111111111111111111111111" -H
> "Accept:       application/vnd.github.v3.raw+json" -i
> https://**MYDOMAIN**/api/v3/repos/**MYOWNERNAME**/**MYREPOSITORY**/git/blobs/***{file
> sha value}***

Error I am getting

> {   "message": "Not Found",   "documentation_url":
> "https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.20/v3/git/blobs/#get-a-blob"
> }
>
> - Connection #0 to host **MYDOMAIN** left intact

we are using GitHub Enterprise solutions.

1. I am not sure I have entered correct SHA value of the file also. Is there anyway to get the correct SHA value ?
2. Is there someone that use this way to access the git file ?

Comment: If you aren't sure if the SHA sum is correct for the blob, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595631/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-blobs-in-a-repository-in-git

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with GitHub Enterprise, but I'm able to perform the following cURL request against a public repository:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/msbit/tools/git/blobs/a6628025e73c505a07305fd25507d0736725474d
```

with the following response:

```
{
  "sha": "a6628025e73c505a07305fd25507d0736725474d",
  "node_id": "MDQ6QmxvYjEyMzQwMzg5OmE2NjI4MDI1ZTczYzUwNWEwNzMwNWZkMjU1MDdkMDczNjcyNTQ3NGQ=",
  "size": 1575,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/msbit/tools/git/blobs/a6628025e73c505a07305fd25507d0736725474d",
  "content": "IyBUb29scwoKQSBncmFiIGJhZyBvZiBCYXNoIHNjcmlwdHMgdGhhdCBJIGhh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\n",
  "encoding": "base64"
}
```

so perhaps the path for the URL you are looking for should be (dropping the `/api/v3` part):

```
https://MYDOMAIN/repos/MYOWNERNAME/MYREPOSITORY/git/blobs/{file sha value}
```

Comment: The `http(s)://[hostname]/api/v3` is correct for GitHub Enterprise integration, based on the docs https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.21/user/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#current-version

Comment: Thanks @BrendanForster, that seems to be all good. It's possibly an issue of getting the correct blob hash; so hopefully OP can use the related question in my comment.